# Echo server with piping to a file

Tags: c, linux

I have a simple echo server and client changed to just send some text to a server. If i use

```
./client.o port < file.in
```

it works and sends file content to a server, but if I try to

```
./server.o port > file.out
```

when starting the server, it won't do anything, neither printing into a terminal, nor to a file. I want to be able to write received text to file if it's specified while starting the server process. Here's the receiving loop from the server code:

```
for(;;) {
        int done, n;
        printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");
        t = sizeof(remote);
        if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *) &remote, (socklen_t *) &t)) == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Connected.\n");
        done = 0;
        do {
            n = recv(s2, str, 100, 0);
            if (n <= 0) {
                if (n < 0) perror("recv");
                done = 1;
            }

            if (!done) 
                printf("%s\n", str);
        } while (!done);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You can force a flush using `fflush`, below is a minimal working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    for (;;) {
        printf("Hey\n");
        fflush(stdout);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use command line arguments(argv) to receive filename and write received text into file.

Comment: The thing is that i should redirect normally without that. I need to make my own netcat program which has variable number of arguments. I just don;t understand why in case of a client it works, but server does nothing, while it actually should just print stdout to a file or terminal, depending on > file statement.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question or help him really in any way